# How to check the checkbox in html table with checkbox id using jquery by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to check the checkbox using jquery on button click by checkbox id. The table which is binded usng jquery only.

**My code is like this**

**Jquery**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) 
{
   a = data.d[i].Id;
   $("#table").each(function () {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#' + a).prop('checked', true);
   });
}
```

Whatever am passing the id and checkbox id is same. Am using this id to check the checkbox but am unable to check it.

please help me how to fix this.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: why not simply  $('input#' + id).prop('checked', true); , since id would be unique, why to iterate ?

Comment: If you place `,` into selector then jQuery consider as two separate selector. So you need to remove  `,`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input#' + id).prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, to toggle checkbox in each row, if the button is inside the row

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
    var check = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    check.prop("checked",!check.prop("checked");
});
```

html would look like

```
<tr> <td><button>Click</button></td> <td><input type="checkbox"></td> </tr>
```

in the loop, you should give set the id for each checkbox:

```
$('#check-' + a).prop('checked', true);
```